# Back-slashing single quotes in Perl

Tags: perl, quotes

I have ran into a situation where single quotes are causing Bash 'unterminated quoted string' errors in a system call. In this specific case I am trying to interpolate the `$DBI::errstr` into the bash commands. I am using in the system call:

```
system "echo '$DBI::errstr' | mail -s 'error' usr@mail.com";
```

So `$DBI::errstr` sometimes contains single quotes and causes errors. I know I can just enclose `$DBI::errstr` in back-slashed double quotes `\"$DBI::errstr\"` and call it a day, but there must be a better way to handle the quotes with out regex or writing a sub routine, which I am having trouble finding. I have also tried `quotemeta` but this will back-slash the spaces too.

Comment: [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote)??

Comment: You can also switch to [Mail::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Mail::Sender) so you don't have to quote anything.

Comment: What is the value of `$DBI::errstr`? Does it have any single quotes in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no good reason to use `system echo` in Perl. You can simply open a pipe as a filehandle and print to it:

```
open my $mail, '|-', qw/mail -s error usr@mail.com/ or die $!;
print $mail $DBI::errstr, "\n";
```

EDIT: but to answer your question in more generality. Instead of relying on the shell to parse and unquote your command-line string and turn it into arguments, it's usually a better idea to use the explicit multi-argument form of `system()`. So, instead of `system "some_command --arg=$val"` and worrying whether `$val` needs to be quoted for the shell, you can use `system("some_command", "--arg=$val")`.

Comment: opening a pipe is perfect for my situation and I am sure the multi-argument form of system() will be very useful in the near future +1

Comment: +1 for a very fluent answer. But `qw/ mail -s error usr@mail.com /` would be nicer; and any `die` should have *something* as a parameter, particularly `$!` if it is appropriate, as it is here

Comment: @Borodin, blame @ikegami for the `'mail', '-s', 'error', 'usr@mail.com'` syntax. Good point about $!. Fixed now.

Comment: The first version of this answer worked fine for me. `open my $mail, "| mail -s 'error' usr@mail.com";` What is the advantage of quoting each part of the shell command?

Comment: The whole point of using multi arg is so a variable can be used for the email address as it should, and `qw` doesn't allow that. The prime reason it looked ugly was the lack of parens, but I didn't want to change your style. You could also use `mail => ( -s => 'error', $email_addr)` if you didn't want to use `'mail', '-s', 'error', $email_addr`

Answer (score 2):

If you were going to use `system`, this is what you'd do:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd1 = shell_quote('echo', $DBI::errstr);
my $cmd2 = shell_quote('mail', '-s', 'error', $email_addr);
system("$cmd1 | $cmd2");
```